# routing in laravel 4.2 loads page but doesn't load styles

Tags: php, laravel

when i am using laravel 4 routing as

```
Route::get("/home", "HomeController@showHome");
```

it works fine but when i am using routing as

```
Route::get("/home/about", "HomeController@showHome");
```

it loads page but doesn't take css and javascript.i tried using named route as

```
Route::get("/home/about" array(
'as'=>'home', 
'uses'=>'HomeController@showHome'));
```

this doesn't work either, it also loads page without styles.

Comment: Can you please provide the html, where you link to the css file?

Answer (score 0):

Use css code as below:

```
{{ HTML::style('css/css.css'); }}
```

Comment: {{ HTML::style('css/css.css');}} is not working, however when i am using {{URL::asset('css/css.css')}} it works, thanks anyway.

Comment: In your method you should write <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/css.css')}}"/>.  But in my method just {{ HTML::style('css/css.css');}}